# How do I fork a gradle groovy compile process using a different Java version?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Groovy project which is mostly built using Java 7, but I want to build one module using Java 8. Following the documentation for the gradle Groovy plugin, I have added the following to build.gradle for the module:

```
// Set up for using Java 8
def java8Home = getJava8Home()
def javaExecutable = new File(java8Home, 'bin/java')
println "Java executable = $javaExecutable"

tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = file(java8Home)
    }
    println 'COMPILE ' + name + ': ' + options.forkOptions.javaHome
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    executable = javaExecutable
    println '   TEST ' + name + ': ' + executable
}
```

Now when I run gradlew project-name:browserTest, I see lines like the following

```
Java executable = ...//jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
COMPILE compileBrowserTestGroovy: .../jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
...
  TEST browserTest: .../jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
...
```

So I expect a forked compile daemon for compileBrowserTestGroovy using Java 8. However I get an error (`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`)showing that it is using Java 7, and I see the following when running with -debug

`16:14:03.760 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 1'. Working directory: /Users/alasdair/workspace/project-name Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/alasdair/.gradle/caches/3.5/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Worker Daemon 1'`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I created a small test project with a java 7 and java 8 module. Set up as suggested it works perfectly. The difference seems to be around 'Worker Daemons' ie looking at the debug output above gradle is starting process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 1' (using java 7), whereas the log from the test project shows

`16:10:30.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':java-8:compileJava'.
16:10:30.581 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] Compiler arguments: -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -d /Users/alasdair/workspace/test-project/java-8/build/classes/main -g -sourcepath  -proc:none -XDuseUnsharedTable=true -classpath  /Users/alasdair/workspace/test-project/java-8/src/main/java/Foo.java
16:10:30.582 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CommandLineJavaCompiler] Compiling with Java command line compiler '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac'.
16:10:30.597 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac''. Working directory: /Users/alasdair/workspace/test-project/java-8 Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac @/Users/alasdair/workspace/test-project/java-8/build/tmp/compileJava/java-compiler-args.txt`

So it seems to be forking and starting a compile with the correct jvm. Why is my main build starting these 'Daemon Workers'? I have in gradle.properties `org.gradle.daemon=false`. I have tried various other things but this remains the question, as it seems to be just creating and using a new daemon instead of forking with the correct jvm as requested

Comment: Can you try: `tasks.withType(Test) { t -> t.executable = javaExecutable.absolutePath }`

Comment: Unfortunatley I haven't got as far as running tests yet - still trying to compile ..